# Customized keyboard shortcut doesn't work in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I was needed to work with Visual Studio at the first time, and the first thing was to customize keyboard shortcuts. I've just changed `Go To Definition` shortcut: `F12` --> `F2`. But it doesn't work. Actually `F2` goes to the beginning of `main.cpp`, meanwhile "the right click and `Go To Definition`" works fine and also displays `F2` as shortcut in right click menu.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have checked for conflicting shortcuts. When you assign a shortcut in the options menu, Visual Studio will show you a list of conflicting shortcuts like this (Visual Studio 2013, but it should be the same):

[image: VS Keyboard Shortcut Settings]

Comment: Solved it! Changed visibility from `Global` to `Text Editor`